# UWP DataGrid - Duplicates with items added asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous, uwp, datagrid

I have a custom collection (implementing INotifyCollectionChanged) bound to a DataGrid via property ItemsSource. This collection is created synchronously but is filled asynchronously (I want to have the UI available with the first items even the filling job is not completed). Curiously, from time to time, I have some duplicates in the DataGrid.

```
public class BaseItemCollection
{
    public delegate void CollectionHander(BaseItemCollection collection);

    public static BaseItemCollection<T> GetCollection<T>(params KeyValuePair<string, object>[] pairs) where T : BaseItem, new() => GetCollection<T>(null, pairs);
    public static BaseItemCollection<T> GetCollection<T>(string procedure = null, params KeyValuePair<string, object>[] pairs) where T : BaseItem, new()
    {
        var collection = new BaseItemCollection<T>(pairs);
        collection.Fill(procedure, pairs);
        return collection;
    }

    public static bool IsCompatible(object parameter) => parameter != null && parameter is IBaseItemCollection;
}

public class BaseItemCollection<T> : BaseItemCollection, IBaseItemCollection, ICollection<T>, IList<T>, IDisposable,
    INotifyCompletion, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged
    where T : BaseItem, new()
{
    private List<T> innerCollection = new List<T>();

    #region Properties

    public object SyncRoot { get; } = new object(); // Use for thread-safe sync
    public KeyValuePair<string, object>[] DefaultParameters { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public Task<BaseItemCollection<T>> TaskFill { get; private set; } = Task.FromResult<BaseItemCollection<T>>(null);
    public CancellationTokenSource TaskCancellationTokenSource { get; private set; }

    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public BaseItemCollection()
    {
        BaseItem.OnItemSaved += Update;
    }

    public BaseItemCollection(params KeyValuePair<string, object>[] parameters)
    {
        DefaultParameters = parameters;
        BaseItem.OnItemSaved += Update;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public void AddFromReader(DbDataReader reader) => Add(BaseItem.FromReader<T>(reader));

    public void Fill(params KeyValuePair<string, object>[] pairs) => Fill(null, pairs);
    public void Fill(Dictionary<string, object> pairs) => Fill(null, pairs.ToArray());
    public void Fill(string procedure = null, params KeyValuePair<string, object>[] pairs)
    {
        // Get the stored procedure name if it has not been specified as parameter
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(procedure)) procedure = StoredProcedures.Get(typeof(T), DataAction.Read);

        // Cancel the running task and wait for it
        if (TaskFill != null)
        {
            TaskCancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
            TaskFill.Wait();
        }

        //Empty the current collection
        lock (SyncRoot)
        {
            innerCollection.Clear();
            innerCollection = new List<T>();
            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }

        // Start filling the current collection
        TaskFill = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var command = BaseItem.GetCommand(procedure, pairs);
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            Parameters.Clear();
            foreach (var pair in pairs) Parameters.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);

            while (!TaskCancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested && !reader.IsClosed && reader.HasRows && reader.Read())
                lock (SyncRoot)
                {
                    AddFromReader(reader);
                }
            command.Connection?.Close();
            FireCollectionFilled(this);
            return this;
        }, (TaskCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource()).Token);
    }

    public T Find(T item) => this.SingleOrDefault(i => item != null && i.Equals(item));

    public void FromUriQuery(string query)
    {
        var parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
        if (parameters == null || parameters.Count == 0) return;
        Parameters.Clear();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> p in parameters) Parameters[p.Key] = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(p.Value);
    }

    public Task RefreshAsync()
    {
        Fill(Parameters.ToArray());
        FirePropertyChanged("Item[]");
        return TaskFill;
    }

    public Task ResetAsync()
    {
        Parameters.Clear();
        DefaultParameters.ForEach(p => Parameters.Add(p.Key, p.Value));
        return RefreshAsync();
    }

    public bool ShouldContains(T item)
    {
        Action<DbCommand> action = (DbCommand command) =>
        {
            Parameters.ForEach(p => command.Parameters.Add(BaseItem.GetParameter(p.Key, p.Value)));
            item.SetParameters(command, true);
        };
        var cmd = BaseItem.GetCommand(StoredProcedures.Get(item.GetType(), DataAction.Read), action);
        TaskFill?.Wait();
        return cmd.ExecuteScalar() != null;
    }

    public string ToUriQuery()
    {
        var qp = Parameters.Where(p => p.Value != null).Select(p => string.Format("{0}={1}", p.Key, p.Value.ToString()));
        return string.Join("&", qp);
    }

    public void Update(BaseItem baseItem, DbDataReader reader)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fired WeakItemUpdate for {0}", baseItem);

        TaskFill?.Wait();

        if (baseItem.GetType() != typeof(T)) return;
        var item = baseItem as T;

        var should = ShouldContains(item); // Should the item be in the list? (using parameters)
        if (should)
        {
            item = this.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Equals(item)) ?? item;
            if (reader != null) item.ReadFromDb(reader, 0); // Refresh the item from the database
        }
        if (this[item] != null && !should) Remove(item); // If item is in the list while it should not => Remove
        if (this[item] == null && should) Add(item); // If item is not in the list while it should => Add
    }

    #endregion

    #region Indexes

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get => innerCollection[index];
        set { innerCollection[index] = value; }
    }

    public bool this[T item]
    {
        get => this.Any(i => i.Equals(item));
        set
        {
            if (value && !this.AnyEquals(item)) Add(item);
            if (!value && this.AnyEquals(item)) Remove(item);
        }
    }

    public object this[string pname]
    {
        get => Parameters.ContainsKey(pname) ? Parameters[pname] : null;
        set => this[pname, true] = value;
    }

    public object this[string pname, bool refresh]
    {
        get => Parameters.ContainsKey(pname) ? Parameters[pname] : null;
        set
        {
            Parameters[pname] = value;
            if (refresh)
            {
                FirePropertyChanged("Item[]");
                Fill(Parameters);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICollection & IList

    public int Count
    {
        get { lock (SyncRoot) return innerCollection.Count; }
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        lock (SyncRoot) innerCollection.Add(item);
        var action = new Action(() =>
        {
            FireCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item);
            FirePropertyChanged("Count");
        });
        if (BaseItem.UserInterfaceAction != null) BaseItem.UserInterfaceAction.Invoke(action);
        else action.Invoke();
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        lock (SyncRoot)
        {
            innerCollection.Clear();
            innerCollection = new List<T>();
            var action = new Action(() =>
            {
                CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
                FirePropertyChanged("Count");
            });
            if (BaseItem.UserInterfaceAction != null) BaseItem.UserInterfaceAction.Invoke(action);
            else action.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        lock (SyncRoot) return innerCollection.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] items, int arrayIndex)
    {
        lock (SyncRoot) innerCollection.CopyTo(items, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        lock (SyncRoot) return innerCollection.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        lock (SyncRoot) innerCollection.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        //lock (SyncRoot) innerCollection.RemoveAt(index);

        lock (SyncRoot)
        {
            var item = innerCollection[index];
            if (item == null) return;
            var res = innerCollection.Remove(item);
            if (!res) return;
            var action = new Action(() => FireCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item));
            if (BaseItem.UserInterfaceAction != null) BaseItem.UserInterfaceAction.Invoke(action);
            else action.Invoke();
        }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        lock (SyncRoot)
            if (innerCollection.Remove(item))
            {
                var action = new Action(() =>
                {
                    FireCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item);
                    FirePropertyChanged("Count");
                });
                if (BaseItem.UserInterfaceAction != null) BaseItem.UserInterfaceAction.Invoke(action);
                else action.Invoke();
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDisposable

    public void Dispose()
    {
        BaseItem.OnItemSaved -= Update;
        TaskFill?.Wait();
    }

    #endregion;

    #region IEnumerator

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => new BaseItemEnumerator<T>(innerCollection, SyncRoot);
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();


    #endregion

    #region Events (INotifyPropertyChange & INotifyCollectionChanged)

    public event CollectionHander CollectionFilled;
    protected void FireCollectionFilled(BaseItemCollection collection)
        => CollectionFilled?.Invoke(this);

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void FirePropertyChanged(params string[] names)
        => names.ForEach(name => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name)));

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    protected void FireCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction changedAction, params T[] items)
        => CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(changedAction, items));

    #endregion

    #region Async

    public TaskAwaiter<BaseItemCollection<T>> GetAwaiter() => TaskFill.GetAwaiter();

    public BaseItemCollection<T> GetResult() => TaskFill?.Result ?? this;

    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get => TaskFill?.IsCompleted ?? true;
    }

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation) { }

    #endregion

    #region Thread-safe

    private void RunSafe(Action action)
    {
        lock (SyncRoot) action.Invoke();
    }

    private T0 RunSafe<T0>(Func<T0> f)
    {
        lock (SyncRoot) return f.Invoke();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And the UI DataGrid (List is BaseItemCollection):

```
            <uwpc:DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" AlternatingRowBackground="WhiteSmoke" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" IsReadOnly="True"
                       ItemsSource="{x:Bind List, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{x:Bind SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single" >
            <uwpc:DataGrid.Columns>
                <uwpc:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=D_From}" Header="From" Width="auto"/>
                <uwpc:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name"/>
                <uwpc:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Title}" Header="Position"/>
                <uwpc:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Site}" Header="Site"/>
                <uwpc:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Manager}" Header="Manager"/>
                <uwpc:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=D_To}" Header="To" Width="auto"/>
            </uwpc:DataGrid.Columns>
        </uwpc:DataGrid>
```

Considering the following items in my collection:

- Item1
- Item2
- Item3
- Item4
- Item5

I can see in my DataGrid:

- Item1
- Item2
- Item1
- Item2
- Item3
- Item4
- Item5

I checked programmatically how items I have in the collection. It returned 5 items and if I select the second occurence of Item1, the first one appears as hightlighted.

Do you know how to fix this? Have some thoughs about Enumerator but would like to have your opinion...
I regularly have some curious behaviors with collection filled asynchronously (see this post: [Curious behavior with ComboBox in UWP - SelectedItem & ItemsSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62020205/curious-behavior-with-combobox-in-uwp-selecteditem-itemssource))

Comment: We can't make a sample to reproduce your issue, could you mind share a demo for us, And for the requirement, you could use `ObservableCollection<T>` type as the item source.

Comment: Working on it, there is a lot of code and comments, just want to make it cleaner...

Comment: Ok, if you have updated the case please let me know.

Comment: I uploaded the code for the collection I use as ItemsSource and the DataGrid used in UI. In the meantime, I'm going to try the same thing with an ObservableCollection and see if I have the same problem...

Comment: I tried your provide code, but it miss a lot of class. Could you make a mini complete sample for us that could be easy for testing.

Comment: I'm doing that.., it's a bit challenging as BaseItemCollection is designed to work with database and has a lot of dependencies, In the meantime, I did some tests and I think it's more an UI issue that happens when the Collection is cleared and loading again in less than one second. It sounds like the UI does not have the time to refresh...

Comment: Well, looks like I had made a big mistake in my code. For some reasons, my event CollectionChanged was fired twice. So the problem is absolutely not related to the UI. My apologies for the lost time :( Not sure how I can close this question...

Comment: Never mind, you could post your solution below and mark yourself.